# VS Code matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I have odd problem with VS Code.
Generally i have function, which allows you to draw two function on one figure. (code below)
In Pycharm i don't have any problems and it shows my plot.
In VS Code i have main fuction, and Jupyter notebook, where i import main and call the function.
There is no fault, but it doesn't show my plot.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string
import random

def compare_plot(x1:np.ndarray,y1:np.ndarray,x2:np.ndarray,y2:np.ndarray,
                 xlabel: str,ylabel:str,title:str,label1:str,label2:str):

    if x1.shape != y1.shape or  min(x1.shape)==0 or x2.shape != y2.shape or  min(x2.shape)==0:
        return None

    else:
        plt.plot(x1, y1, 'b', linewidth = 4)
        plt.xlabel(xlabel)
        plt.ylabel(ylabel)

        plt.plot(x2, y2, 'r', linewidth = 2)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.legend([label1, label2])
        plt.show()

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
f = x + 2
g = x**2 - 2 * np.sin(x) + 3
compare_plot(f, g, x, x, 'x', 'y', 'graphic solution', 'f(x)', 'g(x)')
```

Thank you in advance for help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this out

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string
import random

def compare_plot(x1:np.ndarray,y1:np.ndarray,x2:np.ndarray,y2:np.ndarray,
                 xlabel: str,ylabel:str,title:str,label1:str,label2:str):

    if x1.shape != y1.shape or  min(x1.shape)==0 or x2.shape != y2.shape or  min(x2.shape)==0:
        return None

    else:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
        ax.plot(x1, y1, 'b', linewidth = 4)
        ax.plot(x2, y2, 'r', linewidth = 2)
        ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
        ax.set_title(title)
        ax.legend([label1, label2])
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
f = x + 2
g = x**2 - 2 * np.sin(x) + 3
compare_plot(f, g, x, x, 'x', 'y', 'graphic solution', 'f(x)', 'g(x)')
```